ELD daily log chart in React.js
I would like to create an ELD chart like this in React.js. I tried reading the documents from different chart libraries. However, I was not able to find any that matched the requirements. Please provide me with any method or library to achieve it.

How to create a 24-hour duty status chart in JavaScript or a similar language?
Additional Context:
The chart should visually represent different duty statuses (e.g., off-duty, sleeper berth, driving, on-duty).
Each status should be color-coded and have a corresponding label.
The grid should display the total hours spent in each status.

Since you mentioned you weren't able to find a library for achieving this, here is a crude solution using the HTML Canvas API.


const WIDTH = 900;
const HEIGHT = 200;

const PADDING = 15;

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const noOfHorizontalGrids = 5;
const noOfVerticalGrids = 24;

const horizontalGridOffset = (HEIGHT - 2 * PADDING) / noOfHorizontalGrids;
const verticalGridOffset = (WIDTH - 2 * PADDING) / noOfVerticalGrids;

context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
// Draw the horizontal grid
Array(noOfHorizontalGrids).fill(0).forEach((_, lineNo) => {
  context.moveTo(PADDING, (lineNo + 1) * horizontalGridOffset);
  context.lineTo(WIDTH - PADDING, (lineNo + 1) * horizontalGridOffset);
  context.stroke();
  context.fillText(noOfHorizontalGrids - lineNo, 3, (lineNo + 1) * horizontalGridOffset + 3);
});

// Draw the vertical grid
Array(noOfVerticalGrids).fill(0).forEach((_, lineNo) => {
  context.moveTo((lineNo + 1) * verticalGridOffset, PADDING);
  context.lineTo((lineNo + 1) * verticalGridOffset, HEIGHT - PADDING);
  context.stroke();
  context.fillText(lineNo + 1, (lineNo + 1) * verticalGridOffset - 3, HEIGHT - 3);
});
context.closePath();

const data = [
  { x: 1, y: 3 },
  { x: 8, y: 3 },
  { x: 8, y: 0 },
  { x: 10, y: 0 },
  { x: 10, y: 4 },
  { x: 24, y: 4 },
];

context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.moveTo(
  data[0].x * verticalGridOffset,
  (noOfHorizontalGrids - data[0].y) * horizontalGridOffset,
);
data.forEach(dataItem => {
  context.lineTo(
    dataItem.x * verticalGridOffset,
    (noOfHorizontalGrids - dataItem.y) * horizontalGridOffset,
  );
});
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 16px;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas> 
  </div>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>



Due to time constraint I was able to draw only a simple grid with a square line chart similar to your screenshot.
However, implementing the additional details should not be too difficult. For the Y-Axis, I have displayed numbers. But these can be easily replaced with a list of hardcoded text. Same can be done for the X-Axis.
You mentioned that you need to display some data as color coded, in which case knowledge of the Canvas API is useful.
You can find detailed information about the Canvas API here
